# Multiple Show Text based on Drop Down Menus

Tags: javascript, php, mariadb

I have a bunch of drop down menus, four populated from a mariadb database and called up with PHP and 2 from simple drop downs. I am trying to get these to each print specific text to form one string depending on the values selected but I cannot get them to work together.

I have two of these types:

```
<select name="s_floor_value" id="s_floor_value">
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="7">7</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
              <option value="9">9</option>
              <option value="10">10</option>
              <option value="11">11</option>
              <option value="12">12</option>
              <option value="13">13</option>
              <option value="14">14</option>
              <option value="15">15</option>
            </select>
```

I have four of these that produce different values:

```
<select name="s_site_idnum" id="s_site_idnum">
        <?PHP 
      $sql_s_getsitetype = "SELECT * from locations order by s_name ASC";
$result_s_getsitetype = $conn->query($sql_s_getsitetype);

if ($result_s_getsitetype->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row_s_getsitetype = $result_s_getsitetype->fetch_assoc()) {
      
    echo "<option value=\"" . $row_s_getsitetype["site_id"]. "\">" . $row_s_getsitetype["site_name"]. "</option>";
      
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
      ?>
      </select>
```

I am trying to get the selected options from each drop down to appear as part of a single string but none of the Javascript I have tried to use has worked. I am looking for something simple to get this to work. Anyone have any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: It would be great if you elaborate this problem little bit more or share some code. I believe you are trying to achieve it via JavaScript. Yes, its possible. You ll have to get the selectedIndex of each dropdown and then have to find its value.

Sharing more code will help understanding your question.

Answer (score 0):

The snippet below represents a proof-of-concept, you can test it by running it and changing the dropdown values

```js
let myItems = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth'];

function generateOutput() {
    let outputText = [];
    for (let item of myItems) {
        outputText.push(document.getElementById(item).value);
    }
    document.getElementById('output').innerText = outputText.join(' ');
}

window.addEventListener('load', generateOutput);
```

```html
<select id="first" onchange="generateOutput()">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
    <option value="d">d</option>
</select>
<select id="second" onchange="generateOutput()">
    <option value="aa">aa</option>
    <option value="bb">bb</option>
    <option value="cc">cc</option>
    <option value="dd">dd</option>
</select>
<select id="third" onchange="generateOutput()">
    <option value="aaa">aaa</option>
    <option value="bbb">bbb</option>
    <option value="ccc">ccc</option>
    <option value="ddd">ddd</option>
</select>
<select id="fourth" onchange="generateOutput()">
    <option value="aaaa">aaaa</option>
    <option value="bbbb">bbbb</option>
    <option value="cccc">cccc</option>
    <option value="dddd">dddd</option>
</select>

<p id="output"></p>
```